# How can I change the value inside the data method

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Im trying to show the dialog when I click the Dashboard link. 
The problem is I can't change the dialog value to true since its inside the data method. What's the correct way to do it?

```
  export default {
data: () => ({
  drawer: true,
  dialog: false
}),
props: {
  source: String
},
methods: {
  me: () => {
    alert('me')
  },
  showDialog: () => {
    this.dialog = true
  }
},
computed: {
  months: () => (
    this.months = ['na', 'asd', 'asd']
  )
}
```

}

Here is the layout in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vfztk8ve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed following code in your layout.

```html
<v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
<v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="dialog = false">Save</v-btn>
```

I'd like to say you are in the perfect way to close the dialog and set the component's **dialog** value as **false**.

Actually data method performs like a **variable** rather than a method in component, because we won't share a value in the component across all component instance. Following are [official document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data).

> When defining a component, data must be declared as a function that returns the initial data object, because there will be many instances created using the same definition. If we use a plain object for data, that same object will be shared by reference across all instances created! By providing a data function, every time a new instance is created we can call it to return a fresh copy of the initial data.

Comment: I'd actually want to open the dialog programmatically without using @click directive.

Comment: You are just required to assign a **true** value to **this.dialog** variable in any method, this dialog will be shown. If you don't use @click, when do you wanna the dialog be opened?